# ValueError: Unsupported image shape: ()

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I try to preprocess my train data with resizing, grayscale, and threshold but got error like the title, here is the code

```
train_image = []
for i in tqdm(range(train.shape[0])):
    img = image.load_img('Data/Images/'+ str(train['Id'][i]) + '.jpg', target_size=(400,400,1))
    img = cv2.imread('Data/Images/', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    retval,img = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 1, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    img = image.img_to_array(img)
    img = img/255
    train_image.append(img)
X = np.array(train_image)
```

how to write the right code to preprocess the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected the code by this

```
train_image = []
for i in tqdm(range(train.shape[0])):
    img = cv2.imread('Data/Images/' + str(train['Id'][i]) + '.jpg' ,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    retval,img = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 1, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (400,400))
    img = image.img_to_array(img)
    img = img/255
    train_image.append(img)
X = np.array(train_image)
```

Answer (score 0):

in line

```
img = cv2.imread('Data/Images/', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

no image is specified. It is just a directory.
Use only one method to load images either image.load_image() or cv2.imread()